# js wrong string output

Tags: javascript, html-select

I need to get correct valeu from this string, what I done wrong ?

```
var i = 0;
var ret = '<option value="19">Dep_01_01</option><option value="20">Dep_01_02</option>';
var pre = ret + '<option value="0">NON</option>';
var count = $($.parseHTML(pre)).filter('option').length;
console.log(pre);

for(i=0; i < count; i++){
    var val_drop = $($.parseHTML(pre)).filter("option[value*='" + i + "']").val();
    var text_drop = $($.parseHTML(pre)).filter("option[value*='" + i + "']").text();
    console.log(val_drop);
}
```

the output is :

```
<option value="19">Dep_01_01</option><option value="20">Dep_01_02</option><option value="0">NON</option>
20
19
20
```

but the correct output should be:

```
19
20
0
```

Comment: For starters `i` takes the values 0, 1 and 2, while there is no option with those values

Comment: There are so many problems in there it's hard to know where to start.

Comment: but even I changed the value of NON that represent 0 for any other value its gave the same wrong result. try to add any other numer and you wil get the same result.

Comment: what guys you suggest to do, if I have 2 strings like that and want to get their value as html ?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need any function to do that

```js
var ret = '<option value="19">Dep_01_01</option><option value="20">Dep_01_02</option>';
var pre = ret + '<option value="0">NON</option>';

$(pre).each(function(){
  $('#result').append($(this).val()+" <-----> "+$(this).html()+"<br>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">
```

Answer (score 1):

Same approach:

```
var i = 0;
var ret = '<option value="19">Dep_01_01</option><option value="20">Dep_01_02</option>';
var pre = ret + '<option value="0">NON</option>';
var count = $($.parseHTML(pre)).filter('option').length;

$.each($.parseHTML(pre),function(i,item){
   console.log($(item).val());
});
```

#### Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vhapd1un/

Comment: I'm glad to help @MinaMagdy

Answer (score 0):

First add elements option to a select`.

```
var ret = '<option value="19">Dep_01_01</option><option value="20">Dep_01_02</option>';
var options = ret + '<option value="0">MON</option>';

var elem_txt = '<select>' + options + '</select>'
// Get a DOM object
var elem = $.parseHTML(elem_txt)
var options = elem.find('option')

// for loop
for(var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
   console.log($(options[0]).val());
}

//jQuery each
options.each(function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
})
```

You don't have to recreate DOM objects everytime using parseHTML.

In your test, the matching of [value*=...] seems to be matching the index as a string so you have:

this:

- index: 0 -> 2**0** (**0 is present**)
- index: 1 -> **1**9 (**1 is present**)
- index: 2 -> **2**0 (**2 is present**)

I'm pretty sure that if you do from 0 to 3, you'll have problems with the 3 as nothing will match the css rule.

Comment: thank you, but its ajax function that return this values inside `var ret` and i wanted to add other option when there is nothing, you got me? but really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i did it with split(); see if it helps.

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var ret = '<option value="19">Dep_01_01</option><option               value="20">Dep_01_02</option>';
var pre = ret + '<option value="0">MON</option>';
var count = $($.parseHTML(pre)).filter('option').length;
console.log(count);
console.log(pre)
for(i=0; i < count+1; i++){
var val_drop = pre.split('<option value="');
val_drop = val_drop[i].split('"')[0];
console.log(val_drop);
}
</script>
```